# REACT being able to see immediately the state changed using a useRef hook only inside callbacks. not inside other functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, konva

I have prepared a simple example to show you guys what is my problem.
I declare these variables :

```
const [probeState, setProbeState] = useState(0);
const probeRef = useRef();
probeRef.current = probeState;
```

now If I call this code :

```
console.log(probeRef.current)
setProbeState(1);
console.log(probeRef.current)
```

inside a callback function of a konva component for example, the output will be :

```
0
1
```

instead if I call it inside an useEffect or any other function the output will be :

```
0
0
```

this is an example of the first case inside of a callback function :
parent component return :

```
<Path
   key={"previewPath"+pathKey}
   pathKey={pathKey}
   handlePathMouseDown = {handlePathMouseDown}
/>
```

the component Path :

```
return (
    
      <Shape
        key={"pathLine"+pathKey}
        stroke={strokeColor}
        onMouseDown={()=> {
         
          handlePathMouseDown(pathKey);
       
        }}
/>
```

the callback function:

```
const handlePathMouseDown = useCallback((pathKey) => {      
      console.log(probeRef.current)
      setProbeState(1);
      console.log(probeRef.current)
      
    },[]);
```

from my personal understandings in theory the output should always be the second
because the state will be updated on the next re-render right?
So could you please explain me why is this happening?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Could you show an example that actually produces the output `0 1`? I agree that `0 0` should be expected, as long as the second `console.log` runs on the same render.

Comment: @Taxel you can check the edit now